# Highcharts Solid Gauge with min number NOT zero

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to make a solid gauge using High Chart but I want my yAxis min value to be anything but zero. Whenever, I change the value, the label disappears. Is there a way to make the label appear again? Or maybe someone has an alternative way to make those labels.

In my project, I will have to change the min amount dynamically, depending on user's settings.

Here's a [fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/TH2aB/1/):

```
    jsfiddle.net/TH2aB/1/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the label back by specifying startOnTick:true,

```
 yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        startOnTick:true,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }        
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yU7EM/

You can also explicitly set the tick positions using the tickPOsitions option:

```
tickPositions:[10,200],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6vVr/

Comment: That solved 80% of my problem. Is there a way to make that label reflect the same value set as the min number in yAxis?

Comment: Updated answer. It is easier to set the ticks using the tickPositons option. Note, your code can generate random numbers less than the min of 10 !